# OpenGL generic image reader and GLFW (glfwReadImage, glfwLoadTexture2D) support for various image format

Tags: c++, c, image, opengl, glfw

While learning OpenGL, I am looking for an image reader which can evaluate various image types like `".png", ".bmp", ".tga", ".dds", ...`. My plan is to extract the params like `height`, `width`, `type` of the image file and set it with below kind of function:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, <color format>, <width>, <height>,
    0, <color orientation>, <data type>, <actual data>);
```

I went through [CImg library](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/) and [stb_image.c](http://nothings.org/stb_image.c). However, I couldn't get how to get the parameters like `widhth`, `height`, `type` and so on.

It seems that `<GL/glfw.h>` a nice framework for this. I have an impression that it just loads `".tga"` format using below function:

```
int glfwLoadTexture2D(const char *name, int flags);
```

Does it support all the formats ?

Also, I see the below functions nearby it. If someone can brief about then it will be a bonus.

```
int  glfwReadImage(const char *name, GLFWimage *img, int flags);
void glfwFreeImage(GLFWimage *img);
```

where:

```
typedef struct {
  int Width, Height;
  int Format;
  int BytesPerPixel;
  unsigned char *Data;
} GLFWimage;
```

If GLFW doesn't support all formats then is there any library which just gets the above `GLFWimage` like params and allow us to set it through `glTexImage2D` separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/) has pretty decent support for a broad selection of image formats, but is no longer under active development; the author got too busy.

[GLI](http://www.g-truc.net/project-0024.html#menu) is a good choice as well; it's DDS only, but that's not as big a problem as one might think. Loading JPGs/PNGs/etc. is handy for prototype development (and easy customization by end users), but DDS files are generally a better long-term choice due to their native support for several features which are commonly used in games and interactive applications (BCn [compressed texture formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh308955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), cubic environment maps, volume textures, etc.).

Comment: How about GLFW, is the function mentioned in the question useful ?

Comment: You are correct that glfwReadImage() only loads TGA files. Again, only supporting one image format isn't the end of the world; offline image format conversion tools are a dime a dozen. But if you're only going to support one format, I'd still recommend DDS over TGA.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/) – it's probably exactly what you want.

Comment: How about GLFW, is the function mentioned in the question useful ?

Comment: @iammilind: GLFW has only code for TGA image files. So it's not very generic.